# Empty soap action when SAP Solution Manager call WCF Webservice

Tags: java, wcf, soap, sap-solution-manager

### Context :

SAP Solution Manager (will call it SolMan) exposes a SOAP webservice where a 3rd party can call to interoperate with it. The 3rd party application can also implement the same webservice interface so that SolMan can interoperate in the other direction.
I need to interoperate with SolMan in both directions. My webservice is a WCF Service based on the interface and the types generated from the WSDL of the SolMan webservice with VS2010 "Add Service reference".

### Problem #1

In the WSDL, all of the declared operations has soapAction="". When the service contract interface has been generated from VS2010, all OperationContractAttribute are Action="", ReplyAction="*". Since more than one OperationContract has the same Action (empty string), the Webservice doesn't work, the exception is :

> [InvalidOperationException: The operations AcceptIncidentProcessing
>   and AddInfo have the same action ().  Every operation must have a
>   unique action value.]

Is this normal? There is another way to fix it other than removing all Action="" declarations from the generated ServiceContract interface?

### Problem #2

I've removed all empty string Actions from the generated ServiceContract interface.
I can now inspect the WSDL generated by my webservice and call it with my .net wcf client.
SolMan is unable to call my webservice, after enabling MessageLogging in my web.config, I found that my service has faulted with :

```
<s:Fault>
    <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none" xmlns="">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="en-CA" xmlns="">The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</faultstring>
</s:Fault>
```

Indeed inspecting the SOAP request message shows that soapaction is present in the HTTP Headers, but empty, and that Action is also presents in the SOAP headers and it is also empty .

So I found a Post about the Microsoft's 1DispatchByBodyBehavior1 sample, gave it a try and replayed the http request with Fiddler wihout success. The only way I manage to make it work, is by removing the `<Action>` and `<To>` from the SOAP headers in Fiddler. SolMan will indeed continue to pass these headers.

Is it valid that SolMan sets no Action when calling a SOAP webservice?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe http://spikesoftware.azurewebsites.net/?p=151 can helps you.